# React query-string

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I understand that the query-string library is recommended for processing the URL query strings in a React project. My question will be trivial, it's simply that as a newby I cannot work it out... How is this library receiving to be used within a functional component? Below is simply code, all I want to do is process the URL on launch and do something in response.

In all examples, this component receives a 'props', which is not a value sent into my component (I have a Props, but it is an interface which is sent in by a parent component only).

```html
function Finder(props: Props) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const parsed = queryString.parse();
        console.log(parsed);
        
        /* Do something here */
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the package in reference is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string), `query-string` can use `location.search` as input to the parse method. In the browser, `location` is a global object that represents the URL of the page, and `location.search` returns the query string itself.